# add column value from a 1 row of a table and display the other column

Tags: mysql

I want to add a multiple column and display the other column. Here is my database table:

```
ID | firstname | lastname | score1 | score2 | score3 
1  | mark      | lupez    | 5      | 7      | 4     
2  | james     | cruz     | 6      | 3      | 5
```

I want to add score1, score2 and score3 in every row and display like this:

```
ID | lastname | firsname | total_score |
1  | mark     | lupez    | 16          |
2  | james    | cruz     | 14          |
```

I try to google and find the answer but no luck, my mind is not working though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the score columns:

```
SELECT ID,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       score1 + score2 + score3 AS total_score
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thank you.. simple query I did't expect..  :-)